# Configuring .gitlab-ci.yml file in Gitlab to test python Codes

Tags: python, gitlab-ci

Currently I am stuck with trying to configure the gitlab-ci.yml file. Im trying to automatically build and test my python code when I made a commit. At the moment, I just wanted to build a simple hello world program and purposely put a mistake within the python file by misspelling print (printt instead of print). When I commit, the pipeline is run, but it seems to successfully pass the build and test phase (which it shouldn't).

Any help how to properly configure the gitlab-ci.yml file to automatically test python codes?

I've also attached my current gitlab-ci.yml file.

[image]
Thank you

Comment: For improvement, could you paste your file in the question instead of using an image? You can use the source code formatting to make it look nice :). It will attract answers ;).

Comment: Thank you for the advice David, I've made the changes to my post :D

Answer (score 2):

It's dead simple. Here is minimal working example I use in my repo:

```
pytest:
  image: python:3.6
  script:
    - apt-get update -q -y
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - pip install -r requirements-dev.txt
    - pytest  # or pytest tests/
```

[source](https://henningtimm.gitlab.io/post/first_steps_with_gitlabci/)

Comment: Thank you! this is really useful!

Comment: @EndisSapuandi mark answer as solved if this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Pytest will bring in failed pipleine. like our

[image: Pytest configurations]

[image: Pytest failure]

It would be wonderful if you configure unittests

[image: unittest configuration]

[image: unitest]